# make mrproper vs make distclean in the Linux kernel

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, make

I understood the difference between `make clean` and `make mrproper`.

`make clean` will only remove the generated files (.o/.ko) but not the configuration files and the files in `include/generated`, `include/config`.

`make mrproper` will remove the configuration files as well as files in `include/generated`, `include/config`.

What is the purpose of `make distclean`? `make help` says

> mrproper + remove editor backup and patch files

I added a patch file using `git format-patch -1`, but it wasn't deleted when `make distclean` was executed.

Comment: Your new file was not deleted because the Makefiles had no way of knowing it should not exist.

Comment: What is the patch files which make help is referring to

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`make distclean`](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Makefile?id=a99d8080aaf358d5d23581244e5da23b35e340b9#n1411) builds on top of `make mrproper` (so it deletes everything that `make mrproper` deletes) and in addition:

- deletes [temporary code navigation files](https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/torvalds/linux.git/tree/Makefile?id=a99d8080aaf358d5d23581244e5da23b35e340b9#n1375): `tags TAGS cscope* GPATH GTAGS GRTAGS GSYMS`;
- deletes backup files: `*~ #*# *%`;
- deletes what could more accurately be referred to as “patch artifacts”, *i.e.* files generated as a side-effect of working with patches: `*.orig *.rej *.bak`;
- deletes core dumps.

It doesn’t delete files with a `.patch` extension, such as those generated by `git format-patch`.